# Cell array or matrix for different element's sizes per iteration

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

No code just visually:

```
Iteration i              result j1                  result j2
     1                   10 15 20 15 25                2 
     2                   5                             8
     .                   . . .                         .
     .                   . . . . . .                   .
     i           j1 with length(x), x=0:100        j2 with length == 1
```

edit for better representation:

```
                [10 15 20 15 25]          [1]                (i=1)
                [5]                       [2]                (i=2)
Matrix(i) = [   [. . . . . . . ]          [3]          ]
                [..]                      [.]
                [j1 = size (x)]     [j2 size 1 * 1]          (i=100)

so Matrix dimension is: i (rows) * 2 (columns) 

(p.e for i = 1, j1 with size(x) column 1 on row 1, j1 size (1) column 2 on row 1)
```

I want to save each iterations results to a matrix in order to use them for comparison.
Can this be done with a matrix or its better with cell array and please write an example for reference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sorry, I really can't get what is random and what is not, here. Are your iterations *dependent* one on the other or not?? If you call them iterations probably there is a deterministic dependence of the `i`-th values on the previous, thus you *need cycles*. Otherwise, if there is no coupling and everything is random it looks to me just a problem of *matrix shaping*. Isn't it?

Comment: Matrix shaping is the problem since iterations are independent. Can you give me your way of reshaping? Thank you.

Comment: please consider the answer I gave you. I made my point there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a `cell` array for a cleaner, more intuitive implementation, with less contraints.

```
nIterations = 500;
J = cell(nIterations, 2);
for i=1:nIterations
    length_x = randi(100); % random size of J1
    J{i,1} = randi(100, length_x, 1); % J1
    J{i,2} = randi(i); % J2
end
```

In addition you get some extra benefits such as:

- **Access** an element along and within the cell array

  J{10, 1}; J{10, 2};
- **Append/modify within** each element without changing the overall structure

  J{10, 1} = [J{10, 1}; 0]
- **Append** to the array (adding iterations), like in a normal array

  J{end+1, 1} = 1; J{end, 2} = 1
- **Apply functions** in each entry (vector) using `cellfun`

  length_J = cellfun(@length, J); % get numel/length of J1
  mean_J = cellfun(@mean, J); % get mean of J1

Comment: I ll go this way for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: scroll to profiling for a comparison. (which renders cell-implementation wining.)

---

You can do with a matrix which has `i` rows and 101 colums (values of j1 in the first 100, filled up with `NaN`s (*) when necessary then value of j2),
so then you can do easy comparisons given that it is an unambiguous representation. That is, using 101 columns you make sure j1's do not end with a NaN.

(*){NaN's or 0's depending on which one is more convenient}

You could also do 102 columns where the first column gives the *length* of j1, then comes the value of j1 followed by the NaN's, then the value of j2.
Say `j1=[3 1 10 5]`, `j2=2`, then the corresponding row is `[4 3 1 10 5 NaN ... NaN 2]`.

The benefit of this matrix-approach is

- it should be faster than cells (on not too large number of rows) since Matlab is very good at handling fixed-size matrices.
- Also, basic operations (like comparisons) are slightly easier to program. (you only have to compare two vectors, you can do multiple comparisons on the same line.)

The backwards things with the matrix approach are

- you cannot easily append to j1 (well, a bit easier when you do the 102 column-approach),
- there is a limit on the size of j1. (In this case, 100.)

All in all, cells are slower in general and possibly a bit more lengthy to program with, but more flexible.
I hope this points you to the right direction.

EDIT:

Third approach with 2 matrices:

```
j1results = zeros( n_iterations, maxlen_j1 );
j2results = zeros( n_iterations, 1);
```

Then the computation goes like so:

```
[j1results(k,:), j2results(k)] = compute(k);
```

where the compute is a function that returns two different values.

---

PROFILING:

```
function [J1,J2] = compute(k)
    J1 = zeros(1,100); %this is necessary
    % some dummy assignments
    len = randi(100,1);
    J1(1:len) = k*ones(1,len);
    J2 = k;
end

function res = compute_cell(k) % for the cell-solution
    res = cell(1,2);
    len = randi(100,1);
    res{1} = k*ones(1,len);
    res{2} = k;
end

n=100000;

tic;
J12 = cell(n,2);
for i=1:n
    J12{i}=temp_cell(i);
end
toc

tic;
J1 = zeros(n,100);
J2 = zeros(n,1);
for i=1:n
    [J1(i,:), J2(i)] = temp(i);
end
toc
```

Result:

```
Elapsed time is 2.437634 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.741491 seconds.
```

(Also profiled with `len` distribution of `UNI[50,100]`, where the disadvantage of the matrix implementation of allocating unnecessary memory space would be less dominant, the picture stays still the same.)

**Bottomline**: Surprisingly, profiling says **cell-implementation beats matrix implementation** in every aspect.

Comment: Your answer is understood. Can you write a smple code for predefininf a matrix with zeros for different j1 per iteration? matrix =zeros(length(j1), 1) would be enough?

Comment: Your 101-type matrix should be `matrix = zeros(maxlen_of_j1+1, num_iterations)` or `zeros(maxlen_of_j1+1, 1)` if you just want to return a result from a function. Then you can assign `matrix(k,:) = result(k)` in the k-th iteration.

Comment: Oops, I did it wrong, this is the correct version: Your 101-type matrix should be `matrix = zeros(num_iterations, maxlen_of_j1+1)` or `zeros(1, maxlen_of_j1+1)` if you just want to return a result from a function. Then you can assign `matrix(k,:) = result(k)` in the k-th iteration.

Comment: I check your answer and it returns: "Indexing cannot yield multiple results". Can you clarify it?

Comment: It was my mistake on matrix definition. Thank you for your educative posts.

Answer (score 1):

From your graphic representation one can see that you need a `2xN_Rows` *structure* which **has not a regular pattern** (indeed there is kind of *stochasticity* in it) therefore you must store your data in a way *supporting* such an irregularity. Thus, `cell`s are the natural solution, as others say.

As far as I can see, the elements you need to insert in your matrix, although stochastic, are independent one on the other, therefore you can still fruitfully *vectorize*.

You have `2` stochastic contributions independent one another:

1. the **amount of element** in the first column of your structure is random.
2. the **elements** in your structure are random;

Let us consider separately the contributions:

1. you have `N_Rows`, with a variable number of elements. Let's say that there are `N_El` in the worst case (i.e. `N_El` is an upper bound for the amount of entry per row). Let's generate the number of elements per row doing

   ```
    elem_N = randi(`N_El` , [N_Rows 1]);
   ```
2. you have to generate exactly `sum(elem_N)` random numbers (for point 2.) that will be distributed among the rows after being partitioned according to `elem_N`.

Here is the final code I suggest

```
N_ROW = 20;
N_EL = 10;    
MAX_int = 20; %maximum random integer in each row

elem_N = randi(N_EL,[N_ROW , 1]);         % elements per line stochasticity
elements = randi(MAX_int, [1 sum(elem)]); % elements value stochasticity

     %cutoff points of the vector "elements" among the rows of the structure
cutoffs = mat2cell(...
     [[1 ; cumsum(elem_N(1:end-1))] cumsum(elem_)]... 
     ,ones(N_ROW,1),[2]);



    %result:
res = [cellfun(@(idx) elements( idx(1):idx(2) ) , cutoffs , 'UniformOutput', false ) ,...
     num2cell( randi(MAX_int,[1 N_ROW])')];
```

Result

```
 res = 

[1x9  double]    [20]
[1x3  double]    [12]
[1x5  double]    [ 7]
[1x8  double]    [20]
[1x11 double]    [18]
[1x7  double]    [ 4]
[1x11 double]    [ 1]
[1x4  double]    [15]
[1x5  double]    [18]
```

where

```
  res{1,1}

ans =

    15    13     2     3    20    10     1     2     3


res{2,1}

 ans =

 3    18    10
```

and so on...

Comment: Ok i understand it better now. Be well.